# Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson don't Save

Tags: c#

Faced a strange thing:

I have `Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson` In the code input, I fill it in like this:

```
 private void selectListBox(object d)
        {
            Data data = (Data)d;

            ...

            string oldNick = "none";
            foreach (JObject j in json["data"])
            {
                string com = j.SelectToken("comment").ToString();
                if (com != Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson)
                {
                    if (oldNick == "none")
                    {
                        oldNick = com;
                    }
                    ...
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                BeginInvoke(new setNick1(currentUser));
            }
            Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson = oldNick;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            selectListBox(data);
        }
```

Debugging the end of the code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson = oldNick;
           Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
           Console.WriteLine(Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson);
           Thread.Sleep(10000);
           selectListBox(data);
```

The variable `Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson` has the value I need

But when the method runs again, then `Properties.Settings.Default.oldJson` is set to `none` (this is my default value)

The first time, the method I run in a new thread

Comment: who is calling this method `selectListBox`? main thread ?

Comment: I am calling this method from the main thread